# error: library not found for -lUAirship-1.3.3

Tags: xcode4, push-notification, urbanairship.com

For adding push notifications functionality to my iphone app I use Urban Airship, but the build failed with this error:

ld: library not found for -lUAirship-1.3.3
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

what should I do?
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

IUAirship-1.3.3 needs to be loaded into your project.

Drag IUAirship-1.3.3 into your project. (be sure to check off the option: Copy items into destination group's folder).

Also be sure to link it to your framework by:
Selecting the Target, Click the general tab (at the top), scroll to Linked Frameworks and Libraries, click the + button, add IUAirship-1.3.3

Clean and build:
Next under the Project Menu, select clean. Try building it now. It should be found.

Hope this helps.